# Merging .rr_moved

Tags: iso-image

I have a website archive iso with .rr_moved in root. I'm wondering whether to move it somewhere to make the tree more complete. The site seems to work fine. When I was extracting it, 7z didn't see .rr_moved so I used ultraiso for this, 7z, however, also generated some pop up's about duplicates names.I suppose that's possible if hosted on nix, but I was extracting in win, so I didn't know which to keep. Suggestions?

Comment: I wonder if moving .rr_moved down a few folders will complete the tree and not break any links. Also whether ntfs permits longer pathnames than those by ISO9660 level-1.

Comment: I meant what's inside .rr_moved, not the folder itself.

Comment: *Anything* modern permits longer pathnames than ISO9660 level 1.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the iso was generated with Rock Ridge extensions, but possibly not Joliet extensions. I recommend extracting it on a *nix system and reburning it appropriately.

Comment: After, I extract on nix, I don't think I need to burn it to disk or create another iso. I just want the tree available on win, so I could copy it over. I suppose extracting it on nix will take care of the .rr_moved contents, however I wonder if maybe 7z (on win) has the capacity to handle this properly on its own? In any case, the more important question is, since I plan to use the site on win, how do I keep files with the same names (they were probably different case) and whether html could rely on this different case to locate different files?